# Android GSon serialize double to .net compatible

Tags: android, double, gson

I have an pojo like this:

```
public class LocationPoint {

    protected double la;
    protected double lo;

    public double getLat() {
        return la;
    }

    public void setLat(double value) {
        this.la = value;
    }

    public double getLong() {
        return lo;
    }

    public void setLong(double value) {
        this.lo = value;
    }

}
```

The scenario:
After doing something on a MapView activity I get back to the activity that called id

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    int latitude = data.getIntExtra("Latitude", 0); 
                    int longitude = data.getIntExtra("Longitude", 0);

                    if (latitude!=0 && longitude!=0)
                    {
                                                                                                                                                   LocationPoint p = new LocationPoint();
                        p.setLat((double) latitude);
                        p.setLong((double) longitude);
                    }
```

The int latitude = 43802334 and int longitude = 24825592
The converted values in p are: 4.3802334E7 and 2.4825592E7

I want the double value to be without E7, because the web service throws an error because of it. I am doing something wrong and can't understan why. Can you give an advice ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just had to send from map intent the latitude and longitude as double and as 
clikcedLocation.getLatidudeE6 **/ 1E6**